# Can I install a package in the conda evironment while spyder is running? if yes how?

Tags: package, conda, spyder

As the title of the question
Can I install a package in a conda environment in the background while Spyder IDE is running?

here is the specific example:

I have installed Python, Spyder and a few packages (say numpy, matplotlib and scipy) in a conda environment.

If I then run Spyder and start coding but realise that `import pandas` does not work because I forgot to install pandas in the specific environment, can I install it while Spyder is running?

If I can, how is this done?
So far I had to close spyder, run conda install package-name and rerun spyder